# Programmatically testing memory usage in Google Colab (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to write a program that at a certain level of memory left will write a list to a file to free up memory in Google Colab. I can't  find a way to programmatically test for the amount of memory left using python. To be clear I'm not looking for a way to save to a file (I already know that), I'm looking for a way to test the amount of memory left. The code I'm looking for would work something like this:

```
memory_left = memory_function/method()
if memory_left<=memory_threshold:
    save_file()
```

Another solution would be using the memory profiler package to test the size of an object, and save the file when it gets to a certain size, but I don't think that solution will work because I'm going to have a dynamic environment of ever increasing memory usage. This means there might not be enough memory later on for a file of 100mB, when there are only 10mB left.